# Can I sell my shares that I have losses and gains in and rebuy the gains?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, investing, income-tax

I have some shares where I have big losses and others with big gains. I want to get rid of the shares with big losses completely, but want to use the tax deduction. Can I also sell the shares with big gains and rebuy them? Is that part of the wash sale rule or is that excluded?

Comment: Wash-sale rule only applies to losses, not gains. So you can't harvest gains to offset losses that would be negated by the wash rule.

Comment: So in other words I can do it to reduce my taxes, right? And I can repurchase the shares with a gain immediately?

Comment: No - because gains on share A does not offset losses on share B.

Comment: Are you re-buying the shares that have losses? If so, then the wash rule will exclude those losses, and you'll have tax due on the realized gains. Maybe I'm not understanding the question, but it seems like you're trying to avoid the wash rule somehow.

Comment: No, I'm not rebuying the shares with losses. Only the shares with gains.

Comment: Why are you selling the gains? That would _raise_ your taxes. Why not just sell the losses and take the loss deduction?

Comment: These are all long term. I want to sell them both to make the tax burden net zero.

Comment: Does it work like that?

Comment: It sounds as though you have losses in security A in excess of the (I think) $3000 annual limit, and large gains in security B as well, and you're thinking to reduce your total current + future taxes by selling all of A, plus enough shares of B to offset all but $3000 of your losses in A. And then rebuying B at the new cost basis, which will reduce your future taxes. Is this what you're talking about?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm talking about

Comment: Is your current marginal rate really higher than your long-term cap gains rate? (Is that even possible?) If you want to get the most out of your losses, you should apply them to the highest-taxed income you can. That would be regular income and short-term gains first, then long-term. Note that long-term losses have to be applied to long-term gains first, so all else being equal, avoid incurring long-term gains. (I'm not an accountant nor thoroughly knowledgeable about tax law so I could be wrong, but it seems logically and mathematically obvious to me)

Comment: I'm at max bracket

Comment: So if you apply 3k towards regular income, you reduce your tax burden by 40% * $3,000 = $1,200 (ok, 39.6%, close enough); if you sell and buy for long-term gains, you reduce your taxes by 20% * $3,000 = $600. Double the savings.

Comment: Yeah. That's at 3k. I'm talking about an order of magnitude more. So what I'm saying makes sense, right?

Comment: If you have no / little short-term gain and really want to minimize your taxes this year, sure. But I'd still look at the long-term picture and either: 1. sell just enough losses to cover short-term+3k and hold the rest to sell for future short-term and regular, or 2. sell it all and just roll it over to future years where it can offset more.  The way I see it, long-term gains is the lowest-taxed money you'll ever have, so don't bother / try not to offset it when you can offset income taxed at a higher rate.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the insight. Can I use a long term loss to offset ordinary income tax?

Comment: Also consider that resetting your basis that way resets the capital-gains clock. That means if for some reason you sell it within the next year, any gain from there will be taxed at the higher short-term rate.

Comment: Yes, as long as you have money left over from offsetting long-term and short-term gains, that can offset up to $3,000 of ordinary income.

Comment: @Kevin why not put your comments as answer

Comment: @Dheer I started writing it up but it got longer than I had time for and lost the motivation to finish it

Answer (score 5):

Say you have $6K in losses, and $8K in gains. 
It's clever to use gains to offset losses and vice versa, but consider.

You take $3K/yr loss. It offsets 33% marginal rate income. For 2 years.

You take $8K in gains in other years (not when you take any loss) and you pay long term cap gain at 15%.

This should answer your question.

Comment: That makes sense. If we are talking very large numbers than it would take decades using the 3k limit, right? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Yes, I was taking losses every year until recently from the dotcom bubble. If the number is large you may not want to wait for the decades that it could take it to use them up and in that case just offset them with the capital gains that you have.